# Connecting to a SQL Server Express 2012 from another computer using MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have set up an instance of SQL Server Express 2012 on a computer. On this computer I use MS Access as the client to access the data stored on the SQL Server Express. When I open MS Access and click on an object it then prompts me for the SQL Server username and password (I set up a SQL Server Native 11.0 Driver). This works fine. The goal is to put the file on others computers so they can access the data on our SQL Server. I also have enabled the TCP/IP protocols to allow remote connections as well as the Firewall settings that are necessary. However, when I place the file on another computer, it returns SQL Server Error 53.The strange thing is that I have another computer that I tested this on and it works perfectly fine.

My assumption is that I am missing software on the client computer. What software must be present on the client computers so it will be able to access my SQL Server Express on the "server computer"?

Please let me know if you have any questions, at this point I am stumped.

Comment: [ACE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=13255)? The Access connectivity stuff perhaps?

Comment: Are you using an ODBC connection? If so, it's maybe missing on the 2nd computer

Comment: Is the problematic SQL Server Express instance a Default Instance or a Named Instance? How have you set up Port-mapping for Named Instances of SQL Server?

Comment: Smirkingman,I am using an ODBC connection. WHere would I add it on the second computer? @smirkingman

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I am using the default instance. The port is the default port as well

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ODBC, then on the 2nd computer you need to

- Start->Control Panel->Data Sources (ODBC)
- Select System DSN tab
- Click Add...
- Select SQL Server Native Client
- Give it the **same name** as the name on the working computer
- Select the server to connect to etc.

and you should be OK

Comment: I had not thought about this. I did this and I still get the message that it could not connect. Is there something else I may need to do?

Error I get: A network related or instance specific error has occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or accessible.

Thank you for the help @smirkingman

Comment: I feel that this is of importance:

I have been designing this database on the server computer itself (Remote connection - TeamViewer). When I transfer my client MS ACcess file to my work computer, it allows me to connect. However, transfer my client MS Access database to any other computer, it doesn't work. I don't know what the difference could be?

Comment: Are the 'other' computers on exactly the same network as your 'work' computer?